# Save a text with special characters as "è" or "é" in a file PHP

Tags: php

I've a problem with PHP. I want to save a text with special characters as "è" or "é" in a file .txt in a server. I've tried with this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["textbox1"]) and isset($_POST["textbox2"]) and isset($_POST["textarea1"])){
$file_data = file_get_contents("./posts/num.html");
$num = (int) $file_data;
$num = $num + 1;
$file_data = fopen("./posts/num.html","w+");
fwrite($file_data,(string)$num);
fclose($file_data);

$titolo = $_POST["textbox1"];
$sottotitolo = $_POST["textbox2"];
$testo = $_POST["textarea1"];

$date = date("d/m/y");

$file = fopen("./posts/".$num.".txt","w+");
fwrite($file,utf8_encode($titolo)."\n".utf8_encode($sottotitolo)."\n".$date."\n\n".utf8_encode($testo));

fclose($file);

$ffile = fopen("./posts/".$num.".html","w+");
fwrite($ffile,"<br>");
fclose($ffile);
?>
```

Using utf8_encode, but It isn't working.

Thank you very much for the help.

I want to convert from ISO-8859-1 to ISO-8859-15

Comment: From what encoding are you trying to encode to utf-8? Note that `utf8_encode()` [converts from ISO-8859-1 to utf-8](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php).

Comment: So I was in error. I want to convert ISO-8859-1 to ISO8859-15

Comment: what characters are being written to the file? @EliaD'Amato you need to include that exact result in your question in order for people to see.

Comment: you'll need to ping me as I have earlier with `@` followed by my name or any other member's name. I've left the question, since I can't keep this open for too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso8859-15');
```

And the accent appears. Thank you.